# Using Obj-C that relies on other Obj-C in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

First I want to note, I've read this and have used it before and my question is different:
[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) in Swift.

This library uses OCMock and when I try to compile, I get `'OCMock/OCMock.h' file not found` at the line `#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>`. Here's how I normally fix it, but this time, it's not working.

Just like every other Obj-C library in Swift, I added it to my bridge header, which I already had made and am using for others:

```
#import "JSQMessages.h"
#import "JSQMessageData.h"
```

I then added `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to my Header Search Paths.

Here is the file structure.

[image]

From the project directory, it should look for OCMock/OCMock.h, and it is there, as seen in screenshot. So why isn't it working?

Comment: You haven't explained what isn't working?

Comment: `OCMock/OCMock.h not found` is the error message. I'll add that now.

Comment: Have you added OCMock into you build settings under library search paths?

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and `$(PROJECT_DIR)/OCMock` to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a fresh swift iOS project, add JSQMessage using CocoaPod(http://cocoapods.org). No error. try following:

```
1. Create a new project

2. Create a podfile and add 

    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'

3. Create a bridge header and add

     #import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>    // import all the things

3. Run

    pod install

4. Open project.xcworkspace and build it
```

Comment: That didn't work, but I added `pod 'OCMock'` and that worked. Now I'm getting `Use of undeclared identifier UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`